# Auth.getCurrentUser().$resolved returns false

Tags: angularjs, oauth

I actually use Daftmonk fullstack generator, my problem is sometimes when I try to get the value of `$resolved`, it returns `false` sometimes so I refresh by pressing <kbd>F5</kbd>.

I can login then I get the name of current user on the navbar, but it return false and I can't get email or name of the current User on the body.

Answer (score 0):

I actually found a possible solution in another stack question. The Problem seems to arise from the `client/components/auth/auth.service.js` where there is an issue with asynchronous code.

The fix that worked in my case is making the following change to the `login()` function in the service:

```
  login: function(user, callback) {
    var cb = callback || angular.noop;
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    $http.post('/auth/local', {
      email: user.email,
      password: user.password
    }).

    /* Old code       
    // success(function(data) {
    //   $cookieStore.put('token', data.token);
    //   currentUser = User.get();
    //   deferred.resolve(data);
    //   return cb();
    // }).
    */ 

    /* New code */
    success(function(data) {
      $cookieStore.put('token', data.token);
      currentUser = User.get(function (){
        deferred.resolve(data);
        return cb();
      })
    }).

    error(function(err) {
      this.logout();
      deferred.reject(err);
      return cb(err);
    }.bind(this));

    return deferred.promise;
  },
```

This a copy-paste from the other stack question. The original and more detailed answer can be found here: [getCurrentUser().role undefined in DaftMonk/generator-angular-fullstack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27783014/getcurrentuser-role-undefined-in-daftmonk-generator-angular-fullstack)