# Check role on login

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, local

I have downloaded the yeoman angular fullstack, it comes with the basic configuration for the login.

The code is like:

```
$scope.login = function(form) {
  $scope.submitted = true;
  if(form.$valid) {
    Auth.login({
      email: $scope.user.email,
      password: $scope.user.password
    })
    .then( function() {
     $scope.users = User.query();
      // Logged in, redirect to home
    $state.go('backend', {});
    })
    .catch( function(err) {
      $scope.errors.other = err.message;
    });
  }
};
```

What I want is check the role during the login and redirect him depending of it. I have try with this piece of code but allways return false.

```
          if(Auth.isAdmin()){
       $state.go('backend', {});
      }else{
       $state.go('backend', {});
      }
```

So, I have a question:

**1- It's is stored the user object somewhere in the client side after login? In case afirmative Where? It have all the atruibutes?**

Answer (score 0):

You can find answer on your question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27783014/getcurrentuser-role-undefined-in-daftmonk-generator-angular-fullstack)

Please, note, that currentUser is not set immediately. So here is two ways of struggling with that. In my project we're also using the first one:

```
  if(form.$valid) {
    Auth.login({
      email: $scope.user.email,
      password: $scope.user.password
    })
    .then( function() {
      // need to wait until currentUser will set
      Auth.isLoggedInAsync(function(success) {
        var role = Auth.getCurrentUser().role
        console.log("Role of user is: " + role);
        if(role == 'admin'){
           $state.go('adminpage', {});
        }else{
           $state.go('userpage', {});
        }
      });
    })
    .catch( function(err) {
      $scope.errors.other = err.message;
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: Ohh Thanks a lot, that was my error. Fixed. I took the second option because I think that is better for longer terms.